# How to leverage text to image generation for large format prints?

Tags: image-generation, text-to-image

I’m able to create images that I like with DALL e 3, Firefly, Imagine AI, etc. The problem is the limited size only allows creation of smaller prints. Are there AI tools that can do larger sizes, or tricks to create images that can be combined together?

Comment: So far the best solution I’ve found is to use another AI to upscale images… Still hoping a better solution is released.

Answer (score 0):

MidJourney allows tiling and zoom out to expand the content being generated. However, the output is still fixed size and it is exponentially more difficult to compute image with larger areas. Hence, it doesn't make sense to have an AI tool specifically designed for large format printing. A more reasonable approach would be divide and conquer. The image generation and super resolution should be done separately to achieve the best result.